How to make this lawn THICK, GREEN and Weed Free?
I am new to homeownership and with lawn care and there are so many products and information out on which path to follow for my Bermuda Grass. I live in Knightdale, NC , Comes under zone 8a. I have a builder grade sod in , and obviously it is very bad. I am trying to grow in my thin lawn, lot of dry patches, brown patches(due to very hot summer) which is now recovering. I want to know what schedule to follow, how to thicken my lawn up. Which fertilizers to use and what composition Chemical fertilizer or organic.
Random Weed Coming in here and there, I am removing by my hand with root day in day out. So from here on what should i do. Already applied slow releasing fertilizer, pesticide is done, added liquid aeration since it was new lawn didn't want to do normal one. So what should be my next course of action For THICKER GREEN LAWN ? and preparation for next year?

I removed the word "brand" from your post as I believe that that is the reason someone (not me!) downvoted the question as asking for a shopping recommendation  - and I don't think that is the main thrust of your question.  Also, brand is likely not very important as they will mostly use the same main ingredients - find the type/characterstics of the herbicide/fertilizer you want and then go ask for it at your local garden store.

I'm putting in an answer because this is to big for a comment and does speak to the problem.  (I realize this is not a full answer because I'm not a grass expert- but also think your question is in some ways unanswerable)
The brand of fertilizer is likely unimportant [and maybe off-topic here] - what is important is the NPK mix and micro-nutrients.
Organic vs chemical [I assume you mean petrochemical based] fertilizer may be a bit of a red herring - a better question to ask might be "what will best support the microbiome I want to achieve for my grass to thrive".   I speculate that chemical fertilizer will work better at first - and if your grass can outcompete everything else in this period it will be cheaper and work better - although I would expect others to push back that organic fertilizer will be better long term.
As your grass grows, the amount of weeding you will need to do will decrease because the existing lawn will out-compete the weeds - but while the soil is bare this will likely continue to be a problem.   I'm not advocating it but there are selective weed killers which target broadleaf plants and leave the long leaf plants like grass.   You do get various combined fertilizer and selective weed killers.  Again, I'm not advocating them, but look up "Weed and Feed" (I live in a different country, so can't suggest brands).
I believe the broad leaf killer part of this will be based on the 2,4-Dichlorophenoxyacetic broad leaf weed killer.  Ironically https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%2C4-Dichlorophenoxyacetic_acid says that this is organic - but then again so are arsenic and cyanide.
